# Sitecore package designer timeout on "files statically"

Tags: deployment, sitecore, sitecore6

I've been working on a long term Sitecore project that uses v6.6.  We make extensive use of packages to move from our dev environment to a QA testing environment as well as to the production server.  These packages contain a mix of both items and templates.

Throughout the project, I noticed that whenever I chose "files statically" from the designer to move .ascx files and what have you, it would take a significant amount of time (minutes) to spin up the file browser dialog.

Today it's at a point where it's timing out and I'm unable to add anymore files to the existing package.

I've tried this locally on my dev machine and while very slow, it does eventually come up.  On our dev server both from my local machine hitting the dev URL as well as remoted into the dev server, it times out and gives us a 504/bad gateway.

I've even tried setting a host file entry so that when I'm RDP into the dev server and I browse to the URL, it hits the 127.0.0.1 loopback so it'd save a hop, but it still times out.

My assumption is that there are a lot of files in the project and its puking on that, but I've tried moving the mediafiles/mediacache folders (because they are the largest) out of the normal location to see if it sped things up, and it doesn't.

I'm at a loss for how to fix this.  Is there a way to optimize that file browser, maybe turn off full  recursion so that it loads a folder on demand instead of loading all the files from the file system at once?

Comment: I've opened a support ticket with them as well, so whatever I find, I'll report back here in case someone else runs into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got a response back from the Sitecore homies, and they basically tracked it down to having about 3000 images between two of our folders.  Once I moved those out of the loop, we went from 1+ minute (or timeout) to about 5 seconds.

To clarify, this is simply about the existence of a large amount of files in the website folder, and has nothing to do with how many files are in the package.

I asked them to implement a lazy-load enhancement in the future, but for now, this is what we have to work with.  So, I'll try and keep those folders clean and just work around it.  Thanks to everyone who offered a solution!

Answer (score 1):

You must have quite many files. Although the packager can be slightly dodgy with large amounts of files, I've never seen the behavior you describe. I would raise it with Sitecore Support.

In the mean time; consider making your life slightly easier perhaps, by making your packages dynamic. Now I don't know your configuration, but usually it would be set up something like

- /layouts; pattern *.ascx
- /xslt; pattern *.xsl

And so on. You can save this package definition, and then just "re-run" or re-package it when you require, and would not require you to browse around plucking files to package. It's also quite easy to make mistakes and forget files when doing it manually.

Further reading: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/03/things-to-consider-when-using-sitecore.html

Comment: I'll def. contact support.  Honestly, the file browser has always been really slow to load, but it's become unusable now since it's timing out.

I've used the dynamic stuff before, but as we move through our sprints, we've been using the static stuff for files so that we're only picking files that changed and are relevant to this release.

I do however, use the dynamic stuff for templates since I group my templates by folder if I can help it.  I can then just point a dynamic source at a certain folder and it picks everything up, even if I change a field.

Comment: Maybe dynamic is my workaround here, but I definitely would like to figure out the static file issue.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: A very long time ago; in a very different Sitecore version - the packager would sometimes leave behind excessive files in your windows Temp directory and ultimately fail to work. Now it threw an exception when this happened, but it would be quick to just check it out and see if it does anything for you. I remember writing about it, back then. http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2008/12/sitecore-packager-throwing.html

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Unfortunately, it still spins for about a minute and then times out.  This morning I was able to have it come back just under a minute and it'd return.  Now, perhaps cause more of our devs are hitting the server, it's timing out again.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are having huge amounts of items/templates that you need to transfer between servers. Usually in situations like this it is better to use the Serialization feature of Sitecore. I usually use this approach when I am migrating files from the media library, but it can be used for any situation. If you are not familiar with the feature check [this](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/migrating-huge-amounts-of-sitecore-content-use-the-sitecore-serializer/) amazing blog post by Brian Pendersen which explains the entire process.

Comment: I'm not actually transferring a ton of files.  The timeout occurs when you click the button and it's trying to load the file browser.  That said, I will check out the link, thanks...